# How to validate django form field while it is typing?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

How to validate django form field while it is typing? For example for username field I am want to check if this username already exist

```
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']

    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        raise ValidationError("Entered username already exists")
    return username
```

Comment: You need to implement `AJAX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You can use Ajax to solve this, please check out the code below;*

--**HTML**--

```
{{ form.username | as_crispy_field }}
<medium id="validate_user_name" class="text-muted hidden">
  <font color="red">
    User Name Already Exits!
  </font>
</medium><br />
```

--**JS**--

```
$('#id_username').on('input', function () {
 var id_user_name = $(this).val();
 $.ajax({
    url: '{% url 'validateUserName' %}',
    data: {
        'username': id_user_name
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.is_taken) {
            $("#validate_user_name").show();
            document.getElementById('id_username').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.getElementById("btnAddUser").disabled = true;
        } else {
            $("#validate_user_name").hide();
            document.getElementById('id_username').style.borderColor = "#e7e7e7";
            document.getElementById("btnAddUser").disabled = false;
        }
     }
   });
});
```

--**Django**--

```
def validate_user_name(request):
  user_name = request.GET.get('username', None)
  data = {
    'is_taken': User.objects.filter(username=user_name).exists()
  }
  return JsonResponse(data)
```