# Problem trying to validate django form field while typing

Tags: django, ajax, validation

I'm trying to validate a field while typing based on another question ([How to validate django form field while it is typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220404/how-to-validate-django-form-field-while-it-is-typing)).

The js doesn't cal validation view

**form**

```
{{ form.num }}
<p id="validate_number" class="help is-danger is-hidden ">nome já utilizado</p>
```

---

**js**

```html
<script>
    $('#id_num').on('input', function () {
      var id_number = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'validate-num' %}',
        data: {
          'num': id_number
          },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.is_taken) {
            $("#validate_number").show();
            document.getElementById('id_num').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.getElementById("submit_change").disabled = true;
            }
          else {
            $("#validate_number").hide();
            document.getElementById('id_num').style.borderColor = "#e7e7e7";
            document.getElementById("submit_change").disabled = false;
            }
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

---

**url.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('validatenum/', validate_inventory_number, name='validate-num'),
    # ...
]
```

---

**view**

```py
def validate_inventory_number(request):
    number = request.GET.get('num', None)
    data = {
        'is_taken': InventoryNumber.objects.filter(num=number).exists()
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Do you definitely have an input with 'id_num' as the ID? Does your Ajax request get called? Does the server send any response?

Comment: Yes. I have this code:

<input type="text" name="num" maxlength="200" class="input" required="" id="id_num"> 

And no. The ajax request is not called.